# How to get express get/post latency

Tags: javascript, api, express

Is there a way to get the latency of the request. Like it will return how fast was get/post request?

Is the possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/response-time.html

You can use this middleware which records the time from when a request hits the middleware to when the headers are written out to the client.

or if you're using any web server it can tell you the overall round about time of a request.

Answer (score 1):

You can try coding a way into your request. The date module `moment` is really useful for stuff like this:

```js
const moment = request('moment')

//...
const start = moment()
const result = await myAsyncRequest()
const requestTime = moment(start).diff(moment())
```

Have a look at https://momentjs.com/ for their docs.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic way is using the console.time function.

```
console.time('fooTimer');

const bar =await foo()
bar.filter(...)

console.timeEnd('fooTimer')
```

Console:

```
fooTimer: 20.923ms
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/time

Comment: This question ask for *network latency*, not how long an operation takes.